# In vb.net, How to Map the selected DataGridViewComboBoxColumn value to DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

Tags: c#, vb.net

[image]

**See the image,**

Department Id is  **DataGridViewComboBoxColumn**
Department Name is **DataGridViewTextBoxColumn**

when i select the department id ,that id should display on the textbox.later i may map the id to the Department name. Now the problem i don't how to get the selected **DataGridViewComboBoxColumn value** and assign to **DataGridViewTextBoxColumn**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **Solution** for this problem

> *My complete code is below*

## Form Load Module

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.Add("001");
        bs.Add("002");
        bs.Add("003");
        bs.Add("004");
        bs.Add("005");
        try
        {
           DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            combo1.HeaderText = "DepartmentID";
            combo1.DataSource = bs;
            combo1.Width = 220;
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(combo1);

                DataGridViewTextBoxColumn text1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                text1.Width = 200;
                text1.HeaderText="DEPARTMENTNAME";
                text1.ReadOnly = true;  
                DataGridViewTextBoxCell txt = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(text1);

                DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo2 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                combo2.HeaderText = "Status";
                combo2.Items.Add("Active");
                combo2.Items.Add("InActive");
                combo2.Width = 220;
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(combo2);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("combo error");
        }


    }
```

## dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing Module

```
    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing_1(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (combo != null)
        {
            // Remove an existing event-handler, if present, to avoid 
            // adding multiple handlers when the editing control is reused.
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);

            // Add the event handler. 
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }
    }
```

## ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged Module

```
    private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
        string item = cb.Text;
        int irow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

        if (item != null)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0) // This IF is used for handling first combobox event in gridview
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[irow].Cells[1].Value = item; // cell index [1] represent DepartmentName
            }

        }

    }
```

## Output

[Click here to view Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4Ot0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have a datatable as a source. If yes, in the click event of the datagrid view get the selected value

```
Dim strValue as String = dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).Value
```

now loop through your datatable and get the appropriate department with the  selected id and get the value to place it on the textbox column. something like this

```
Dim row AS DataRow = DataTable.Select("ComboboxColumn = strValue").FirstOrDefault()
If Not row Is Nothing Then strTextBoxColumn = row.Item("ComboboxColumn")
```

Now assign the value to the textbox column on the datagrid view

```
dgv.rows(e.rowIndex).Cells(DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).Value = strTextBoxColumn
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.. @Leprechaun